# Convert char pointer hex to a string and save in text file C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I create a dll that is injected in a process and return a hex value for example : 570AC400. I have a function of type `__int64 GetLocalPlayer_EX()` that return this hex values, but text saved in txt return strange string like  @*░B

```
char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(GetLocalPlayer_EX());//GetLocalPlayer_EX() is function return hex value
std::string str(ptr);

printf("LocalPlayer = %s\n", ptr);//print to test, but return strange string like  @*░B should be 570AC400


void WriteLogFile(const char* szString)//convert char hex to string and save in txt
{


    FILE* pFile = fopen("C:\\TesteArquivo\\TesteFile.txt", "a");
    fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", szString);
    fclose(pFile);


}

WriteLogFile(vOut); // call function to save txt file
```

PS: if I use `printf("LocalPlayer =%I64X\n", ptr);`, the return hex value is correct.

Comment: What happens if you change to `printf("LocalPlayer = %s\n", str);`? (Sorry, put the wrong thing.)

Comment: return stranger string like i said =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the raw int back from the function. You shouldn't cast it to a char*. Try this:

```
__int64 rv = GetLocalPlayer_EX();

printf("LocalPlayer = %ld\n", rv);
printf("LocalPlayer = %X\n", rv);
```

but I wonder if the signature of the function is correct. Does it really return `__int64` and not a `ClientPlayer*` ?

Edit:
Since it seems to be a pointer in disguise,

```
char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(GetLocalPlayer_EX());
printf("%p\n", ptr);
```

Comment: is Int64 but return adress(hex value), dont want just print, i want convert to string, print is just for me check if was converted correctly

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: i got now, in my function WriteLogFile i change fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", szString); to fprintf(pFile, "%I64X\n", szString);

Comment: Ok, but since you are printing a pointer address and not a string or number, why not use %p which is there for just that purpose?

Comment: Btw, do you have the header describing ClientPlayer? I assume you're using the DLL with this export?
`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)ClientPlayer* GetLocalPlayer_EX()`

Comment: yes i have this, but i get error "Attempt to read or write to protected memory. Usually, this is an indication that another memory is damaged."  when i try call the function from my c# app, then i create a txt file that will get all this adress hex and  i read from my c# project, is not the best ways but is i can do

Comment: SO suggests that we move this discussion to a private chat. That's ok for me if you'd like. Anyway, consider this cast instead:
`ClientPlayer* cp = reinterpret_cast<ClientPlayer*>(GetLocalPlayer_EX());`

Comment: how i can talk with you in private with this topic??

Comment: I just noticed that it's based on reputation here on SO (I'm new here myself) so we can't take it to the chat section, yet it suggests it :-) I don't know what negativity it'll bring if we just keep the discussion here so it's best to not push it too far.
Anyway, your print of garbage characters looked like 4 bytes (32 bits) so I guess you're on a 32 machine. If that's correct, I would not use a printf format string that forces 64 bits to be read (if that's what %l64X implies). Use %p.